# Filter array based on a value in nested array with Ramda

Tags: ramda.js

I'm trying to learn Ramda, but I'm struggling with seemingly simple stuff. How would I write the filter and sort using Ramda's pipe?

```
const items = [
  { id: 1, subitems: [{name: 'Foo', price: 1000}]},
  { id: 2, subitems: [{name: 'Bar'}]},
  { id: 3, subitems: [{name: 'Foo', price: 500}]},
  { id: 4, subitems: [{name: 'Qux'}]},
]

const findFoo = value => value.name === 'Foo'

items
  .filter(item => item.subitems.find(findFoo))
  .sort((a, b) => a.subitems.find(findFoo).price > b.subitems.find(findFoo).price ? -1 : 1)

// [{ id: 3, subitems: [...] }, { id: 1, subitems: [...] })
```

I've tried something like this but it returns an empty array:

```
R.pipe(
  R.filter(
    R.compose(
      R.path(['subitems']),
      R.propEq('name', 'Foo')
    )
  ),
  // Todo: sorting...
)(items)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ramda's [`sortBy`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#sortBy) may help here.  You could just do the following:

```js
const findFoo = pipe (prop ('subitems'), find (propEq ('name', 'Foo')))

const fn = pipe (
  filter (findFoo),
  sortBy (pipe (findFoo, prop ('price')))
)

const items = [{id: 1, subitems: [{name: 'Foo', price: 1000}]}, {id: 2, subitems: [{name: 'Bar'}]}, {id: 3, subitems: [{name: 'Foo', price: 500}]}, {id: 4, subitems: [{name: 'Qux'}]}]

console .log (fn (items))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const {pipe, prop, find, propEq, filter, sortBy} = R                  </script>
```

Obviously if we tried, we could make this entirely point-free, and address the concerns about double-extracting the Foo subobject.  Here's a working version that converts the elements into `[fooSubObject, element]` pairs (where the former may be nil), then runs a filter to collect the elements where the `fooSubObject` is not `nil`, sorts by their price, then unwraps the elements from the pairs.

```js
const fn = pipe (
 map (chain (pair) (pipe (prop ('subitems'), find (propEq ('name', 'Foo'))))),
 pipe (filter (head), sortBy (pipe (head, prop ('price')))),
 map (last)
)

const items = [{id: 1, subitems: [{name: 'Foo', price: 1000}]}, {id: 2, subitems: [{name: 'Bar'}]}, {id: 3, subitems: [{name: 'Foo', price: 500}]}, {id: 4, subitems: [{name: 'Qux'}]}]

console .log (fn (items))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const {pipe, map, chain, pair, prop, find, propEq, filter, last, sortBy, head} = R</script>
```

But to my eyes, ***this is a horrible, unreadable mess***.  We can tame it a bit by extracting a helper taking a function to generate the gloss object we will need for filtering and sorting, and our main process function (that actually *does* the filtering and sorting) using the `gloss` function to create the `[gloss, element]` pairs as above, calling our process and then extracting the second element from each resulting pair.  As per Ori Drori's answer, we'll name that function `dsu`.  It might look like this:

```js
const dsu = (gloss, process) => 
  compose (map (last), process, map (chain (pair) (gloss)))

const fn = dsu (
 pipe (prop ('subitems'), find (propEq ('name', 'Foo'))),
 pipe (filter (head), sortBy (pipe (head, prop ('price'))))
)

const items = [{id: 1, subitems: [{name: 'Foo', price: 1000}]}, {id: 2, subitems: [{name: 'Bar'}]}, {id: 3, subitems: [{name: 'Foo', price: 500}]}, {id: 4, subitems: [{name: 'Qux'}]}]

console .log (fn (items))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const {compose, map, last, chain, pair, pipe, prop, find, propEq, filter, head, sortBy} = R</script>
```

This is better, and maybe marginally acceptable.  But I still prefer the first version above.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [DSU sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform):

1. Decorate - map the original array, and create a tuple with the `price` of the found item in the sub-array, or `-Infinity` if none, and the original object.
2. Sort by using the `price` (the 1st item in the tuple).
3. Undecorate - Map again an extract the original object.

```js
const { pipe, propEq, find, map, applySpec, prop, propOr, identity, sortWith, descend, head, last } = R

const findItemByProp = pipe(propEq, find)

const dsu = (value) => pipe(
  map(applySpec([ // decorate with the value of the item in the sub-array
    pipe(
      prop('subitems'),  // get subitems
      findItemByProp('name', value),  // find an item with the name
      propOr(-Infinity, 'price') // extract the price or use -Infinity as a fallback
    ), 
    identity // get the original item
  ])),
  sortWith([descend(head)]), // sort using the decorative value
  map(last) // get the original item
)

const items = [{"id":1,"subitems":[{"name":"Foo","price":1000}]},{"id":2,"subitems":[{"name":"Bar"}]},{"id":3,"subitems":[{"name":"Foo","price":500}]},{"id":4,"subitems":[{"name":"Qux"}]}]

const result = dsu('Foo')(items)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-t0vPcE8ynwIFovsylwUuLPIbdhDj6fav2prN9fEu/VYBupsmrmk9x43Hvnt+Mgn2h5YPSJOk7PMo9zIeGedD1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Inspired by this, I added a version that creates a higher-order `dsu` function.  I can see many uses, although in the end I would use it over my simpler version only if there were demonstrable performance problems.  At some point, Ramda had a function that worked like this, or so I remember.  I'll look around and see if I can find it, or find what happened to it.

Comment: Nice! The generic DSU is concise. I liked the chain(pair). I started with chain but couldn't find a way to create the tuple.

Comment: I've used the technique often enough, but never before thought to extract it to a stand-alone function.  `chain` and `ap` on functions are really nice.  `chain(f, g) //=> (x) => f(g(x))(x)`.  and `ap(f, g) //=> (x) => f(x)(g(x))`.  This means that if we want to work with `[original, gloss]` records instead of `[gloss, original]`, it's only a slight tweak:  `const dsu = (gloss, process) => compose (map (head), process, map (ap (pair) (gloss)))`.